# UI of Pentaho Report Designer too small

Tags: user-interface, settings, pentaho, scaling, pentaho-report-designer

I've recently downloaded many versions of **Pentaho Report Designer** (prd) and I face the same problem : the user interface is way too small on my 1920*1080 screen.

How can I increase the dpi and the icon/font size ?

*I work on Windows 10.*

Comment: you can change the windows setting and increase the perception, nothing you can do at prd level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use PRD 8.1, on Windows, in `report-designer.bat` I change the following parameter to java launcher

```
-Dswing.useSystemFontSettings=true
```

For icons, Java JDK 9 and above should be able to fix it automatically because it will scale with the Windows DPI. Although, DPI can be changed with

```
-Dsun.java2d.uiScale=2
```